# TWS-API and ib_insync: Order Status is not updated properly

Tags: algorithmic-trading, interactive-brokers, tws, ib-api, ib-insync

I'm trying to place an order using the TWS-API and the python package [ib_insync](https://ib-insync.readthedocs.io/api.html). However, I recognize that the order status is not updated by TWS automatically. Please consider the following snippet:

```
stock = Stock('BMW', 'SMART', 'EUR')
ib.qualifyContracts(stock)
order = MarketOrder("BUY", 10)
trade = ib.placeOrder(stock, order)
```

A look into the order status of the trade just made (i.e. with **trade.log**) reveals the order to remain in the *submitted* state. For that, see the following screenshot:

[image]

Highlighted with the red box, you see the log-command printing the order state "submitted". At that point in time, though, the order got already filled when looking into the TWS.

Interestingly, if I now run **ib.sleep()** (highlighted in green) and look into the order state afterwards, I can see that the order's state has changed to filled (see blue box). This behavior is what I observed several times. Only after typing **ib.sleep()** the order state seems to be updated in accordance to what is happening in the TWS.

Shouldn't the state of the order automatically be updated by the TWS-API, or do I really need to update the order myself by quering the state from the TWS API?

Any kind of guidance is greatly appreciated. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Register the callback function for the 'orderStatusEvent'. This enables you to track the status of the order effectively.

```
self.ibsyn.orderStatusEvent += self.on_order_status

def on_order_status(self, trade: Trade):
  """Updates Order Status from ib insync"""
    logger.debug(f"onOrderStatus: {trade}")
    if trade.orderStatus.status == OrderStatus.Filled:
    ...
```